# Vertically center responsive image in responsive div with CSS

Tags: css, image, layout, responsive-design, vertical-alignment

**EDIT** - As requested here's the Fiddle **jsfiddle.net/daghene/eq4tfzLn/**

I've already searched a lot on Stackoverflow and Google to find an answer to this but even if there's plenty I don't know why they're not working nor if I'm handling this layout correctly.

Basically I'm using Skeleton responsive framework to make a one-page layout and I have a section where there's a row with this image on the left and text on its right. Below it there's a small twitter paragraph with the latest news.

Basically my problem is: when the first row gets too small and the text starts getting long the image gets way too small and I thought the best solution is to vertically center it, but both it and the div's height are responsive(most solutions requires at least one of the two to be fixed height).

**What's your suggestion** and far more importantly **am I handling this layout well** on a logical perspective or is it ok to have paragraphs get THAT long with the image simply sticking to the top?

*Note that it displays fine on desktop, tablet and smartphones*, there's just that little part where it gets kinda weird...***here's the screenshot of how my layout is acting***, the third one being the one that I think should be fixed since it's kinda ugly to look at and maybe centering the image would help.

[image]

P.s. one thing I forgot, haven't put my code since Skeleton, as most responsive Frameworks, simply requires a *.container* class with *.row* and *.X columns* inside it to give the divs size and centering and I didn't add anything on top of that yet. The only thing I think I'll do is put the sections in a fixed height's div because I plan on making the user scroll them as slides and they'll always need to be 100% viewport height or at least a fixed height like say 600px scaling.

P.s.2 if the only solution is js since we don't know the paragraph's and img's height at all times go ahead and propose a solution, I'm asking if this could be done with CSS since I'm not that good at js yet.

Comment: please show a fiddle with the actual (minimal) markup of that block and update your question with a link

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan I don't know how to make a good Fiddle since I'm using Skeleton, Normalize, Jade and Sass and it all results in a single html file and a single css file with all the messy stuff in it.

Would it be better if I uploaded the page as it is right now or is JSFiddle still better now? I'm trying to make a Fiddle right now but I don't know how to include Skeleton and such without having the CSS pane full of stuff.

Anyway as I said there's basically nothing, it's just: body > .container > .row(Skeleton stuff so far) > div class=thanksup and div class "thanksdown, on the ame level.

Comment: I'm guessing there are some kind of media queries at work here but what does your framework use to position the cells left and right?  I would say for default you should use `display:table-cell` (which will allow you to vertical align your content) and then when you get below 565px; change this to block.  As you have provided us with no code, I wouldn't be able to tell if this would work with your structure, but that's the way I would do it

Comment: Yes you can use media queries and apply style for each in different width. Then we can obtain like this

Comment: Sorry guys for not providing code earlier, I updated the original post and loaded normalize + skeleton and added my code, hope this is clear enough since I pasted in the preprocessed code with its indentation.

Here's the link! http://jsfiddle.net/daghene/eq4tfzLn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would give the `thanksup` row an id - eg `vertical` and then you can use the following styles to achieve vertical alignment:

```
#vertical {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
#vertical > .columns {
    float:none;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle
}
@media (max-width: 565px) {
  #vertical  > .columns {
    display: block;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kh3n6us9/2/)

Comment: Thanks Pete, this is doing exactly what I wanted.

On a design perspective though do you think I should still handle it this way or it's probably better to simply force the two items to stack on top of each other when the paragraph is becoming too long?

It's looking good now but it still feels that centering the image near that long paragraph is a bit of a stretching, what do you think? I'm giving you the accepted answer since it's doing the job but if you could still give me a tip on how you would handle it from the "beauty" side of it it would be appreciated!

Comment: Just saw that there's a weird spot between 566px and 581px where the two items are stacked up in a column on the left of the screen, why is that happening?

Comment: If I have content left and right like that it's usually a thumbnail with a summary so it never gets styled into the long column with white space.  If it's an image with a lot of content, then I would either have it on top as a thin long banner or as part of the text as a photo: http://jsfiddle.net/t70bu2h6/.  But I guess it's really personal preference and as a developer, what I often think looks good, I get told by the designers is complete rubbish!

Comment: Ah, just checked and your media query kicks in at 550px and sets a width of 48% on the divs.  Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/kh3n6us9/3/

Comment: Thanks, changing to 550px worked! That was easy but if you didn't point it out I wouldn't see it, I'm learning the framework right now and I'm struggling a bit so thank you.

I also like the idea of nesting the text and the image as you showed in your Fiddle and I'll code that version now but that would break the "cleaneness" of the layout I originally made. It's struggling on smaller screens as you saw but the original idea is this one and it looks elegant on bigger and smaller screen so I'd love to keep it as is if possible.

**Here's the layout as I'd like it** http://imgur.com/Bxc05dZ

Comment: Yeah, that is quite nice but I would only see that working if there isn't too much text.  A good way to learn to see what the framework is doing is to use chrome or ff and right click on an element and inspect it - it will show you all the styles applied to it so you can see what is happening

Comment: I did that but for some reason it didn't work well because I was using the smartphone emulator and the code kept changing even if I wasn't changing the viewport, pretty weird.

So basically you'd say I should cut down the text or go for the solution you proposed rapping the text and the image together? I even thought about scaling the text making it smaller only for that specific 200px where it looks too long and before getting into the stacked view but that's another thing and I should see it on screen probably.

Comment: Ah yeah, may not work with emulators as it will probably class the emulator screen as an element that could mess with some of the styles.  I'd probably go with the wrap for that one - unless you are able to make the text size and line-spacing smaller without making it unreadable or messy

Comment: That's what I'll try to do right now, just got back to my office and will see which option works best. Thanks again for all the help and tips Pete, much appreaciated!